# Why `selector` value is not found elsewhere and can I change it?

Tags: angular

I developed components and services using `ng generate`, and all are working in my Angular v11 app. But this one thing I'm clueless, value for `selector:` never found elsewhere except in the component's own TS file. So you know I'm pretty green on Angular, pardon if you think questions are stupid.

**Question 1. how does Angular know/link/map it into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?**

For example, `ng g component login` generates login.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',      // <-- only appearance of 'app-login'
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{...}
```

I know it will be plugged into placeholder `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` upon routing inside of app-rounting.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = 
                [{ path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent }];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],    
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Question 2. If I want to change it from `app-login` to `hello`, where and what do I need to update?**

Simple and plain English is better to understand, thank you and appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to break this apart.

> value for `selector` is never found elsewhere except in the component's own TS file.

Now for this one, as long as this `component` belongs to a `module` along with other components that can be found in the **`declarations`** array for this specific `module`, then this `component` is visible and the `selector` for this `component` can be used within any other `component` in the same `module`.

Now if we want this `component` to be visible even outside its `module` that it belongs to, then we need some extra configuration. We have to add it to the `exports` array in this case. And by importing the entire `module` in our target `module` we can have access to this `component`. This can be useful when you have a shared `module` that will be used across the app.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Now in my `LayoutModule` for example, i can import the `SharedModule` and gain access to its components.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    LayoutPageRoutingModule,
    TranslateModule,
    SharedModule, <- Imported Here
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutPage],
})
export class LayoutPageModule {}
```

Getting back to your questions:

> **Question 1. how does Angular know/link/map it into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?**

That's done when you tell Angular that this "*link*" corresponds to this `component`, and you tell it that with this line here

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent }];
```

Now every time you hit this link, the `component` will be rendered **inside the `router-outlet`**.

> **Question 2. If I want to change it from app-login to hello, where and what do I need to update?**

That's the easy part, you just change the `selector`, nothing else need to be configured, because basically what really matters is the **class name, associated `HTML` & `CSS` files name, relative paths**.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',   // <-- Change it just like this, and start using it as <hello></hello>
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent{...}
```

**Note:** Pay attention to not use a pre-reserved tag in HTML, as this could cause a problem (*i.e. `selector: div`*), this `app-` prefix is there to prevent such a problem.

Hope this helped.